# mi consulta mysql sale vacia

Tags: mysql, sql

buen dia estoy tratando de hacer un inner join
para traerme el nombre y apellidos de mi registro por medio del usuario session
el problema es que al hacer la consulta me manda vacio el campo

```
SELECT *
FROM datos
INNER JOIN registro ON usuario = apellidos where id_prof=SESSION EJMPLO'prueba4';
```

tengo dos tablas una donde tengo los datos a imprimir y otra donde esta el registro del usuario
registro
datos

tabla datos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

tabla registro

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Este segmento `ON usuario = apellido` no me parece tiene sentido, puedes por favor editar y agregar la estructura de tus tablas

Comment: ya los puse hay editados

Comment: Las imágenes son bastante difíciles de apreciar, por favor solo coloca en forma dfe lista cada tabla por su nombre y sus columnas, de paso agrega si esta consulta devuelve algún error por que noto involucra algo de PHP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En ta tabla registro no tienes ningun campo llamado 'usuario' y tampoco tienes capturado el apellido en esa tabla, lo que puedes hacer es esto:

```
SELECT *
FROM datos
INNER JOIN registro ON datos.id = registro.id 
where id_prof=SESSION EJMPLO'prueba4';
```

Asi le estas diciendo que te muestre los datos de usuario 'prueba4', cuando los 'id' de las dos tablas coincidan

Comment: ya me salio pero no me lo muestra

Comment: $consulta="SELECT nombre,apellidos FROM registro, datos WHERE registro.usuario=datos.id_prof AND id_prof=".$id;
$resp=mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta) or die ("Error consulta nombre: ".mysqli_error($conexion));
$fila=mysqli_fetch_array($resp);
$nomcomp=$fila['nombre']." ".$fila['apellidos'];

Comment: Este segmento puede dar error `id = id` de ambiguedad si ambas tablas lo tienen, además lo que se debería igualar en la igualdad es  la llave primaria y la llave foránea a que tabla corresponden no?

Comment: una observacion más, en tu tabla registro en el campo id_prof, no estas capturando ningun id, entonces nunca va a encontrar los datos